# How to copy and paste while using clipboard tag?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am using pace automation framework .There is tag called clipboard tag. How to use clipboard to copy and paste. Is there a possibility to perform this action?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to copy and paste using clipboard Tag
Example Code:

```
        <activity id="fillFormDetails">

                          <input id="userNumber" value="00900700999"/>
                          <dblClick id="userNumber" />
                          <specialKeys xpath="//input[@id='userNumber']" specialChar="{control}+a"></specialKeys>
                          <specialKeys xpath="//input[@id='userNumber']" specialChar="{control}+c"></specialKeys>
                          <clipboard varName="var"></clipboard>
                          <input id="currentAddress" value="${var}"/>

         </activity>
```